Rotating Towards the Anchor Point while Swinging
So I've been working on a Spider-Man like game for my company and I need some help with the web-swinging. Specifically, rotating in the character in the direction of the anchor point so the swinging looks natural. Here's the code I've written:
private void AdjustRotation()
{
    Vector3 dir = playerStateMachine.SwingTarget.position - playerStateMachine.transform.position;
    Quaternion targetRot = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, dir);
    //targetRot.y = 0;
    //targetRot.z = 0;

    playerStateMachine.transform.rotation = targetRot;
}

My function calculates the direction of rotation, then creates a from-to rotation and then rotates the character. The issue I'm facing is that my characters doesn't face the direction of the swing. It always faces its forward direction.
Here's a video demonstrating the problem. Please help me out.

Do you have access to velocity information that will tell you which direction the character is swinging toward?

Yes I do have access to the velocity info.

Then you can use the velocity as the approximateForward input to the TurretLookRotation helper method I show here. Does that handle what you need?

@DMGregory ur method makes the Z-vector face the target. I want my character's up vector to face the target. Can u help?

The method lets you control both the up (y) vector and the forward (z) vector. It sounds like you just put the arguments in the wrong order.
